# SortedSet.Remove () not working with custom comparer class

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am trying to solve a leetcode problem, where I want to get top k frequent numbers. I am trying to solve it using SortedSet for O(log n) time complexity.

My code is working for all inputs **except** one particular input.

```
public class FreqNode
{
    public int number;
    public int freq;

    public FreqNode(int n, int f)
    {
        number = n;
        freq = f;
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 10, 11, 5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6};

        TopKFrequent(arr, 10);
        Console.Read();

    }        

    static void TopKFrequent(int[] nums, int k)
    {
        SortedSet<FreqNode> sl = new SortedSet<FreqNode>(new MyComparer());
        Dictionary<int, FreqNode> ht = new Dictionary<int, FreqNode>();

        foreach (int i in nums)
        {
            if (ht.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                sl.Remove(ht[i]);
                ht[i].freq += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ht[i] = new FreqNode(i, 1);
            }
            sl.Add(ht[i]);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            FreqNode f = sl.ElementAt(i);
            Console.WriteLine(f.number);
        }
    }
}

public class MyComparer : IComparer<FreqNode>
{
    public int Compare(FreqNode fn1, FreqNode fn2)
    {
        //Remove entry with same number
        //Retain entries with same frequencies.
        if (fn1.number == fn2.number)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int res = fn2.freq.CompareTo(fn1.freq);
            if (res == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints output as - 1,2,5,3,7,**6,6**,4,8,10

instead of - 1,2,5,3,6,7,4,8,10,11

During debugging, I noticed that Comparer code does not compare with existing entry of number 6. After further investigation, I found that, SortedSet is implemented using Red-Black tree, but I could not resolve this bug in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was interesting to me because I thought it might be a SortedSet bug and had me stepping through the SortedSet source.  Alas, not a SortedSet bug...sorry but your IComparer is a bit wonky.

Your IComparer implementation does weird things to the comparison by first changing the criteria of sort comparison, then by inverting the comparison objects, then by changing the return value.

First your comparer is saying,

> if "number" properties are equal, the nodes are equal (this is fine)

```
if (fn1.number == fn2.number)
{
    return 0;
}
```

then it's saying

> sort on the inverse of the freq property (switching fn2 with fn1 is probably not a good idea, and the criteria of sort has changed to the 'freq' property (probably ok))

```
int res = fn2.freq.CompareTo(fn1.freq);
```

then it's changing equal freqs to not be equal

> if the result of the 'freq' comparison was equal, let's pretend like it's not equal (probably not a good idea)

```
if (res == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
```

The poor SortedSet's root must be rotating!! (HAHAHA!! I made a Data Structures joke!!  get it "root"? "rotating"?)

In the end, the Remove algorithm looks for the '6' as a right child because your IComparer tells it that's where it should be, meanwhile '6' is actually a left child, so the Remove algorithm misses it.

As an aside, keep in mind that the 2 '6' nodes in your SortedSet and the '6' node in your dictionary are all actually the same FreqNode reference, so you can change all of them at the same time if you needed to.

You can look at (and download) the .NET source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedset.cs)
then set up Visual Studio to debug sources by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2017)

Lastly, if you insist solving the top-k problem this way, try this comparer:

```
        public class MyComparer : IComparer<FreqNode>
        {
            public int Compare(FreqNode fn1, FreqNode fn2)
            {
                return fn1.number == fn2.number ? fn1.freq.CompareTo(fn2.freq) : fn1.number.CompareTo(fn2.number);
            }
        }
```

Cheers and thanks for a fun debug!

Comment: Thanks a lot Christo. I want to keep entries with same frequencies in SortedSet. Therefore, I included "return 1" logic. Please suggest a way to keep entries with same frequencies without screwing underlying data structure.

Comment: @AkshayP You're welcome.  I'm not sure I understand "keep entries with same frequencies...".  Please explain.

Comment: Imagine you are getting constant stream of numbers and you want to store them with increasing/decreasing order of frequencies. You might have different numbers with same frequencies. If we use your comparer class, then SortedSet will not have two nodes with same frequencies. I added "return 1" code as a work-around, but it did not work, as I hoped. Please suggest if there is a way to create sorted collection of possible duplicate values with time complexity of insertion and retrieval near O(logn).

Comment: ??It certainly does have multiple FreqNodes with same 'freq' value.  It will not have multiple FreqNodes with the same 'number' value.  So, sorry, I still don't understand what you want.  If you have a stream of values and want to keep them around, store them in another data structure [SortedDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) perhaps?  [SortedList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)?